# How to run standard linux commands in nocache mode automatically?

Tags: linux, cache

There is a way to run commands in Linux without caching the result, i.e:

```
nocache cat big_file.txt
```

Is there is a way to make this nocache mode automatic? Something like a global setting.

The problem: I have a lot of vendor scripts that use `cp` or `find` or other standard commands, and I do not want them to clutter my cache.

Comment: do you mean you don't want the files context is begin cached?

Comment: Why don't you want them being cached? They use memory on your system, but they are removed from memory when any application needs memory to run.

Comment: @alphamikevictor yep, but i use memory for mysql already

Comment: What I mean is you don't need to worry about it, linux kernel will manage it in the right way.

Comment: IIRC, if you use InnoDB it does it's own caching and the linux blockdev/filesystem cache should matter less. The other thing is, forcing IO to be direct the script(s) will now potentially contend with mysql for IO which may be just as bad.

Comment: What is triggering those vendor scripts to run repeatedly? Just run *that* thing within `nocache`. Anything started by it will inherit the same environment. However, I think you really want cgroups with disk or memory usage limits/minimums instead of simply disabling the cache.

Comment: The `nocache` command has some (to me) unexpected performance issues. Be careful how you apply it, and to which commands. I made the mistake of applying it to a shell script, and things did not go well. Try running `time /bin/true` and `time nocache /bin/true` -- the use of `nocache` adds a full second of CPU overhead to every command I try. (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 v4 @ 3.50GHz)

Answer (score 2):

I'd really like to discourage doing this, as it may end up just as disruptive. You'll essentially now force a whole lot more IO, which may well (depending on your setup) end up contending with mysql for IO which would be just as bad.

If you really must, make wrappers for cp/find/etc in a separate directory and stuff it first in PATH for the vendor script(s) execution environment. I.e.

```
mkdir /opt/evil
echo -en "#! /bin/bash\nexec nocache /bin/cp \"\${@}\"\n" >/opt/evil/cp
chmod a+x /opt/evil/cp
# repeat for find and any other things you want to be run with nocache
export PATH=/opt/evil:${PATH}
vendor-script.sh
```

Additionally - if you use InnoDB, IIRC it does it's own in-process caching and does not rely (as heavily) on the linux pagecache.

Comment: The legitimate use-case of backup is described in the nocache manpage, e.g., see https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/nocache/nocache.1.en.html . Agree this is a bad thing to try to default to: let your OS decide. I would use wrappers named differently, e.g. 'cp-backup' or `rsync-nocache` in `/usr/local/bin` or elsewhere on path, and selectively use them in specific circumstances. Maybe rsync already does this!

Comment: It would be nice to have `rsync` option to call `posix_fadvise()` with `POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE` for source or target files as needed but it doesn't seem to have such a feature. Note that it doesn't make sense to *default* to such flags because in generic sense it's better to let the kernel decide. Note that for some uses you would want the NOREUSE flag for the source, target or both. And just putting `nocache` in front only handles the "both" case.

Comment: The `nocache` command has some (to me) unexpected performance issues. Be careful how you apply it, and to which commands. I made the mistake of applying it to a shell script, and things did not go well. Try running `time /bin/true` and `time nocache /bin/true` -- the use of `nocache` adds a full second of CPU overhead to every command I try. (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 v4 @ 3.50GHz)

Comment: @IanD.Allen Nope, the nocache version was faster 0.015s on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Even you don't need to worry about it, you can delete memory cached files when you want just issue this command as root

```
sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

[Here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) you can find more info.

EDIT:
Following the link if you echo 4 then linux will completely disable the caching of files, which is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'd at the very least limit it to just page cache (echo 1), and not also drop all the metadata. I'd drop the sync as well, if there is dirty data in cache, dropping it should force flush. You're also going to interfere with everything else that might benefit from the pagecache, and you'll also momentarily make mysql suffer painfully as you essentially just requested  everything doing IO to stop right now while all IO is flushed and caches re-populated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand alphamikevictor's link correctly, echoing "4" into drop_caches only disables the log messages, not the caches.

One could add an alias to ~/.bashrc for the various commands. For example:

alias cp='nocache cp'

(assuming bash is your shell.)

The same thing could be put into /etc/bash.bashrc to affect all bash users on the system.

Comment: This llikely won't work as I'm not sure that non-interactive shells will do much in terms of sourcing rc-files/profile-files unless you have bash invoked with --login. Aliases are also not inherited across fork/exec.